# Groovy: Difference with a.intersect( b ) and b.intersect( a )

Tags: arrays, groovy, intersect

Why in Groovy, when I create 2 lists, is there a difference if I do a.intersect( b ) and b.intersect( a ):

```
def list1 = ["hello", "world", "world"];
def list2 = ["world", "world", "world"];

println( "Intersect list1 with list2: " + list1.intersect( list2 ) );
println( "Intersect list2 with list1: " + list2.intersect( list1) );
```

traces:

```
Intersect list1 with list2: [world, world, world]
Intersect list2 with list1: [world, world]
```

(you can copy it here: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ if you want to test it)

If the arrays all contain unique elements, then it works as normal. Once you begin to add duplicates, it gets weird:

```
def list1 = ["hello", "world", "test", "test"];
def list2 = ["world", "world", "world", "test"];

println( "Intersect list1 with list2: " + list1.intersect( list2 ) );
println( "Intersect list2 with list1: " + list2.intersect( list1 ) );
```

traces:

```
Intersect list1 with list2: [world, world, world, test]
Intersect list2 with list1: [world, test, test]
```

I thought the whole point of `intersect()` was to give you the common elements, so it didn't matter which order you put them in?

If this isn't the case, how can I get only the common elements (expect duplicates in the array). E.g. example one should return `["world", "world"]` and example two should return `["world", "test"]`

**Edit**

To clarify a bit, this code should test that user data is still the same (assuming they disconnected in the middle of something and we want to make sure the data hasn't been tampered with, or is in the same state as before).

The order of the lists can't be guaranteed (the user could reorder it, but it's still technically the "same"), and duplicates are possible.

So something like: `["one", "one", "two"]` should match `["two", "one", "one"]`, whereas any addition to the lists, or change in data shouldn't match.

Comment: Note: `def array1 = ["hello", "world", "world"];` does **not** create an *array* in Groovy. It's a `List` (specifically an `ArrayList`)!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at [the source for `Collection.intersect`](http://git.codehaus.org/gitweb.cgi?p=groovy-git.git;a=blob;f=src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java;h=82445bc4767d008d0be03e0c69de4d4c0c1068df;hb=HEAD#l8516), you can see that the logic of the method follows this flow:

for two collections, `left` and `right`

1. Swap `left` and `right` if `left` is smaller than `right`
2. Add all of `left` into a Set (removes duplicates)
3. For each element in `right` if it exists in the `leftSet`, then add it to the results

So, for your last 2 examples;

```
def array1 = ["hello", "world", "test", "test"]
def array2 = ["world", "world", "world", "test"]
```

`array1.intersect( array2 )` would give (if we wrote that same algorithm in Groovy):

```
leftSet = new TreeSet( array1 ) // both same size, so no swap
// leftSet = [ 'hello', 'world', 'test' ]
right   = array2
result = right.findAll { e -> leftSet.contains( e ) }
```

Which (if you run it), you can see means result has the value `[world, world, world, test]` (as you found).  This is because every element in `right` can be found in the `leftSet`

Not sure why the first example should return `["world","world"]` though...

### later...

So, what I think you are looking for would be something like this:

```
def array1 = ["hello", "world", "test", "test"]
def array2 = ["world", "world", "world", "test"]
def intersect1 = array1.intersect( array2 ) as TreeSet
def intersect2 = array2.intersect( array1 ) as TreeSet
assert intersect1 == intersect2
```

in order that you cope with the duplicates in the collections, as then both `intersect1` and `intersect2` will be equal to

```
[test, world]
```

### later still

I believe this does what you want:

```
[array1,array2]*.groupBy{it}.with { a, b -> assert a == b }
```

Comment: "Not sure why the first example should return `["world","world"]`" - basically i'm trying to see if a list has changed between 2 different times (server code - i want to make sure the user has the same data when he comes back and it's not been tampered with). In the first example, there's 2 occurences of `"world"` in each list, which is why I was looking for a result like `["world", "world"]`

Comment: thanks for the code example, but it won't work with something like `array1` as `["hello", "world", "world"];`, while `array2` is `["hello", "hello", "world"];` - they both contain duplicates, but using `TreeSet` will assume both lists are the same (as duplicates are removed)

Comment: @divilly Ahhhh...  That's true...  Can you explain more what it is you're trying to do?  And why `assert ["hello", "world", "world"] != ["hello", "hello", "world"]` isn't enough?  I'm not sure `intersection` is going to help you here...but with our combined powers, we _must_ be able to come up with a working algorithm...

Comment: ok, got it working with the following: 1) check size of array1 and array2 before. if they're different, then fail. 2) `def array3 = new ArrayList( array1 );`, 3) `array2.each { array3.remove( it ); }` 4) if array3's size is 0 at the end, they're the same

Comment: @tim_yates For that last one, couldn't you just do `assert array1.sort() == array2.sort()`?  This would be a lot easier to understand what's happening!

Comment: @Over yeah...  Though you probably want Groovy 1.8.1+ and `array1.sort( false )`, as otherwise `sort` actually changes the order of `array1`