# Antijoins with Groovy Collections

Tags: collections, groovy, relational-algebra

This is probably a silly question however, is there a simple way of doing antijoins of collections in Groovy?

I know there are [equivilent ways of doing unions and intersections].

My thought on how to do this is:

```
List a,b; 
union(a,b) - intersection(a,b)
```

However, I'm not sure if there is a difference operator for collections in groovy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that can you can do a subtraction operation on 2 lists, and receive a list back of the disjoint collection. Just use the subtraction operator between two lists.

```
 listone - listtwo
```

Comment: Watch out if you have duplicates in the lists though

Comment: It depends on what [you require as the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386978/groovy-difference-with-a-intersect-b-and-b-intersect-a)

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, there isn't an operator our method to do this for you (might be a cool addition to groovy though)

The closest I can think of is [the disjoint method](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/03/groovy-goodness-intersect-collections.html) which returns true if there is no intersection between lists, and false otherwise